# How does the kinetic-molecular theory explain why atmospheric pressure is greater at lower altitudes than at higher altitudes?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, fluid-statics, atmospheric-science, gas

It is believed that pressure exerted by a gas is caused by "momentum exchanges by colliding molecules".

Also it is a fact that the atmospheric pressure on a body is greater at lower altitudes.

**Then, does this mean that a body at lower altitude has more molecules colliding with it than one at high altitude?**

Answer (score 2):

That is exactly what it means.  The pressure at a specific height above the ground is proportional to the amount of gas above you.  As you go up into the atmosphere, you have less gas above you (the density decreases with height) and therefore less pressure.  A good simple webpage covering this is [here](https://flexbooks.ck12.org/cbook/ck-12-middle-school-earth-science-flexbook-2.0/section/10.3/primary/lesson/pressure-and-density-of-the-atmosphere-ms-es).

Mathematically $$\frac{dP}{dh}=-\rho g$$

Where $\frac{dP}{dh}$ is the change in pressure with height, $\rho$ is the gas density and g is the acceleration due to gravity.

If you assume the density changes according to the ideal gas law, then $$P_h=P_o e^\frac{-mgh}{kT}$$ where $P_h$ is the pressure at height h, $P_0$ is the pressure at your reference level (e.g. surface of the Earth), k is Boltzmann's constant and T is the temperature.